# toolbar dirty rendering syncfusion documenteditorcontainer

Tags: syncfusion

I'm testing documenteditorcontainer from syncfusion. I've followed the [start guide](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/document-editor/getting-started/) but I'm not having the expected rendering.

Here is the rendering
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs as DocumentEditor’s dependent component styles are not referred in *styles.css* file. So, please add below CSS reference in your *styles.css* file to resolve this issue. 
Seems this information is missing in the documentation, we will refresh it.

```
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-lists/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-splitbuttons/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material.css'; 
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-documenteditor/styles/material.css';
```

Note: I work for Syncfusion.